# Zipping together zip files

Tags: ubuntu, zip, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use the apt package "zip" to zip together some files to simplify the process on the other end for a non-technical person. For organization I wanted to make a zip file of a few zip files in case they only actually want one portion.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how exactly to do this though. I can run `zip -r test.zip directory` and it works fine, but if I run something along the lines of `zip test.zip firstDirectory.zip secondDirectory.zip` I get 0% stored.

I been thinking that it might prohibit this to stop people from making zip bombs, but there should be a way to do this legitimately, no?

I realize I can just put every file in one big zip file, but I would rather not if possible. Also I don't have a gui, so preferably if this requires any new packages they should work through cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the zip command says `0% stored`, it means "I was unable to achieve better than zero percent compression of this already-compressed data, and have decided that it would be more efficient to simply place the file as-is in the new zipfile". Try adding a text file to a zip, and you'll see something like `93% deflated`... which means "I achieved 93% compression, using the 'deflate' algorithm".

Comment: Oh, awesome! I had no idea. Thanks so much! Any idea why it says the same thing when trying to include a directory without the -r flag? Is is just storing the directory address?

Comment: My understanding is that a directory is stored in a zip file as a zero length file, and is distinguished from an actual zero-length file by having a trailing '/' at the end of the filename. Zero-length files, too, are incompressible.